# Trying to login to SO with curl. 'Object moved'

Tags: php, bash, curl, stack-overflow

I am trying to login into SO with Curl request.
I did 'copy as curl' in Chrome Devtools but looks like not working.

The Curl request is:

```
curl 'https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f' -H 'origin: https://stackoverflow.com' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'cookie: prov=73eb5c72-b3a8-8b68-31f0-a2d253eff6d0; fkey=6a845300596f0345303f5224b648485c' -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,/;q=0.8' -H 'cache-control: max-age=0' -H 'authority: stackoverflow.com' -H 'referer: https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f' -H 'ws-grp: 95' -H 'dnt: 1' --data 'fkey=6a845300596f0345303f5224b648485c&ssrc=head&email=mojmail%40gmail.com&password=mojeHaslo&oauthversion=&oauthserver=&openidusername=&openididentifier=' --compressed
```

and the response is only :

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>

<h2>Object moved to <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">here</a>.</h2>

</body></html>
```

Any ideas how to get it working?

Comment: It might be a redirect response. Try `curl -L`

Comment: Just add -L to what I have?

Comment: yes `curl -L 'https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?...`

Comment: not working. Getting response with SO start page without login

Answer (score 1):

The URL which you're trying to hit is not direct. It needs to redirect to other link. You have to provide `L` parameter before the link.

```
curl -X GET -L https://www.mywebsite.com
```